# Craft2: Images are not being loaded properly from “cpresources/”

Tags: craftcms

I've copied the asset folders which fixed most of the webpages, however specific images (namely from cpresources/) still giving 404s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether PHP module `gd` is enabled and add the following line to your `config/general.php`:

`'imageDriver' => 'gd',`